# Verify that nginx is running

Tags: nginx

If nginx `init.d` script does not take status option (like Apache) - how could I possibly know if it is running or not? I can verify `nginx` process exists but it does not tell much.

Comment: It depends on which distro/package you installed from. So, it can be either you modify the init.d script to include the status option or find an init.d script that supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except checking that process exists, you can always check `netstat -tulpn | grep nginx`

```
 # netstat -tulpn | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4158/nginx.conf
```